# Python: How do I make a button freeze when I press it? - Tkinter

Tags: python, button, tkinter

This is a memory game where the user selects two buttons (cells). If the two words behind the cells match, the words stays visible else the cells goes hidden and u can't see the words behind them. What I want to do is to make a cell freeze if it shows the word behind it when it is pressed. I want to apply that function to both choice1 and choice2 and even to the pairs that the user have already found.

I have tried to change `self.hidden = not self.hidden` on line 16 to

```
if self.hidden:
    self.hidden = False
else:
    self.hidden = False
```

but that didn't work out pefectly.

Here are the important part:

```
from tkinter import *
import random

class Cell:
    def __init__(self, word, hidden = True):
        self.word = word
        self.hidden = hidden

    def show_word(self):
        """ Shows the word behind the cell """
        if self.hidden:
            self.hidden = False
        else:
            self.hidden = False
        self.button["text"] = str(self)

        if mem.choice1 is None:
            mem.choice1 = self
        elif mem.choice2 is None:
            mem.choice2 = self
            mem.update_tries()
        else:
            choice1, choice2 = mem.choice1, mem.choice2
            mem.choice1, mem.choice2 = self, None
            self.check(choice1, choice2)

    def check(self, choice1, choice2):
        """ Checks if the chosen words are a pair """
        if choice1.word != choice2.word:
            for cell in (choice1, choice2):
                cell.hidden = True
                cell.button['text'] = str(cell)

    def __str__(self):
        """ Displays or hides the word """
        if self.hidden:
            return "---"
        else:
            return self.word

class Memory(Frame):
    """ GUI application that creates a Memory game """
    def __init__(self, master):
        super(Memory, self).__init__(master)
        self.grid()
        self.create_widgets()
        self.tries = 0
        self.choice1 = None
        self.choice2 = None
```

Comment: What is the question you're asking? Are you asking about how to toggle the value of self.hidden? `self.hidden = not self.hidden` works fine, no need to replace it with anything.

Comment: If u click a cell, the word behind the cell shows up instead of "---". The problem is if the user is stupid and press the same cell again. The cell goes hidden and shows "---". I don't want it to go back to "---". I want it to "freeze" and still show the word.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could disable the button when it should not be clickable anymore:

```
cell.button.config(state = DISABLED)
```